# How to change grpc maxReceiveMessageSize in chef?

Tags: go, chef-infra, rcp

I am trying to run CLI command to check the license usage and I am immediately hit with the exception below which can be solved by increasing the `maxReceiveMessageSize`, I am wondering if anyone knows if this can be configured somewhere for chef.

Command:

```
chef-automate license usage
```

Failure:

```
a request to the deployment-service failed: request for usage info failed: rpc error: code = resourceexhausted desc = grpc: received message larger than max (4453604 vs. 4194304)
```

Github [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/rpc_util.go#L573) to where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: A gRPC message marshaled maxsize is hardcoded to 4MB. So if an API is not chunking it's response, then there may be limited options to workaround it hitting this limit.

Comment: @colm.anseo I can see one possible way around this, which is by setting [MaxCallRecvMsgSize](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#MaxCallRecvMsgSize)... but I don't see how that is possible in chef without code changes...

Comment: To reiterate what @colm.anseo already said in terms of future proofing: If your gRPC message is already too large, then what is to stop it from overrunning an altered `MaxCallRecvMsgSize` in the future? You may be tempted to keep it as a `Unary`, but an unbounded message size necessitates using a `Stream`.